# How to add trailing slash to url using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I am using following htaccess code to redirect the page without extension. it's working fine but now i need to add slash at end of the url how to add i tried lot of nothing is working.

here is my code

```
#Alternate default index page
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On

# browser requests PHP
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
 RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# check to see if the request is for a PHP file:
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
 RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
```

also i have another problem, while using this config. I tried to call "api/apis.php" file via ajax post request but request failed. request converted to GET like "api/apis".

Answer (score 1):

You just need to disable `POST` method in first redirect rule:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On

# browser requests PHP if request method is not POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# check to see if the request is for a PHP file:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```